# Setting HTTP Timeout in Group policy through Active Directory

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, group-policy

I am facing a "Page cannot be displayed" error whenever I access a website(that is under our support) through a computer that is bound to a **particular AD**. This "Page cannot be displayed" is shown when I cannot get a reply for HTTP request **within 1 min**. If I access the same page in another machine (that is not bounded to this AD) gets a reply (though the reply takes more than 1 min).Is there is a specific group policy configuration that I need to look for this?

Thanks